# How can I upload TeamCity's artifacts file into diawi (https://www.diawi.com/)

Tags: android, ios, teamcity

I'm using Diawi to upload iOS files i.e. .IPA file

For that I have created TeamCity build job for creating .IPA from iOS code.

Now, I want to upload that file to Diawi - So my team can directly downloaded it from that.

Please let me know , If there are other options if possible.

Comment: You can also use Testflightapp for ipa distribution for testing

Comment: Can you provide me more details on this.
So I can do this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is project [diawi-cli](https://github.com/theJenix/diawi-cli), that let you upload your application to Diawi from command line.
So just clone this utility during Teamcity build (add VCS root for example) and add a [command line](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Command+Line) build step that will upload your application or artifact.